# Biological Reactor through Genetic modification?

Tags: biology, energy, body-modification

As all of you know, humans eat for energy. While being able to maintain homeostasis is great, it's also human to want more. Maybe we want stronger muscles, or the ability to breath fire, or even to use some form of magic (once we've figured out how to use the energy in a meaningful way). We'd probably need more energy than we can currently metabolize from food. So, assuming:

- We can edit human biology with ease and,
- We've already figure out a way to use the energy

What is a plausible way that a biological reactor (using fusion, or some other fuel source) can exist in (highly modified) humans? What would it look like? What assumptions must be made (about the editing process) to make that a reality?

Of course, if I've made any impossible/wrong assumptions, please correct me.

Comment: How "highly modified"?  (Note that fusion is definitely a non-starter.)

Comment: So you want some sort of entirely biological nuclear reactor? And you want it to produce chemical energy that can be used by biological tissue in the body, not electrical energy to run cybernetics? If so, I'd suggest you change your title to make that clearer, since a bioreactor is something very different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioreactor

Comment: Highly highly modified, they might look like human but we could have rearranged most of their biology. As for powering cybernetics, that's a start, but something fully biogical (and potentially can be inherited) is preferred

Comment: The energy released from nuclear fusion is NOT the same kind of energy as that created by and used by the human body.  You'd need something like Star Trek replicators to convert between the two.  The radiation produced is 100% deadly to biomatter and while biology is pretty good at breaking apart molecules and reasonably good at stitching them together, there is no precedent for biology taking two atoms and forcing them together into a new atom.  Are you willing to remove the entire "(using fusion...)" parenthetic?  Like @RonJohn said, fusion (and all other nuclear reactions) is a non-starter.

Comment: BTW, I love your user description.  "Brain filled with crazy" goes a long way on this site.  Cheers.

Comment: Something that's given me trouble answering this: the *way* these energy problems are handwaved have unbelievably vast implications regarding what can be done biologically around them.  I mean, currently we don't even know how to sustain fusion in large scale mechanical settings like laboratories.  Understanding how to fit a fusion generator into human biology would depend almost completely upon how the heck you achieved fusion in the first place.

Comment: This question needs serious work: It is absolutely central that you talk more about the form of energy you desire. Electric, chemical, mechanical (pressure?), thermal, they all have pros and cons in terms of what they can do and what they do TO You ---- also, define reactor: does this "reactor" need to have any true reaction (chemical OR nuclear fusion OR nuclear fission, all completely different) or would e.g. a coil to pick up ambient wireless energy (that was output for that pupose) also qualify? Should we just handwave some source and tell you more about conduits? Please be more precise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nature has ready done its best with <strike>midi-chlorians</strike> mitochondria. You won't get better than that just biologically. Another problem with biology is in how fast energy can be extracted. But if you allow for the extraction of energy from the body to power machinery, then it can be done.

When I was in college I had proposed such a thing for my final thesis.

Mammary implants are mosty made of a silicon gel. That gel has no function other than being volumous. I thought we could add some features to it by adding some flash memory and a class one bluetooth antenna (good for one meter), so that a woman with such implants could do things like storing music in her breasts and send it to headphones. I even planned for a volume knob to replace the nipple, but at this point my advisor told me to get out of her office and not come back until I had a better idea for a thesis.

Electronics need power, and I had that part figured out. We could use a hollow tube with three rare-earth magnets in it - one stuck to each end and one floating free in the middle. Also inside the tube we would fit a solenoid. Just like the setup of a mechanically powered flashlight:

[image: Shake, shake, shake, señora!]

When the middle magnet goes through the solenoid, electric energy is generated, which can then be used to power some system. The idea was to have an array of these tubes be placed vertically inside the prothesis, so that the owner could generate energy by running or jumping. So she would be converting her calories into up to 5 volts of direct current, powering up a Playstation 3 controller battery which would feed the flash memory and the antenna. But when I finished explaining this part to my advisor I got kicked out of the office again.

Anyway... You could adapt this idea so as to have **thousands, maybe millions of microscopic versions of these tubes spread through the muscles and/or abdominal cavity of your cyborgs**. They would charge their bionics largely by moving around. If you wish them to be sedentary, though, you may develop a single muscle that keeps contracting and relaxing throughout the day - using the same kind of muscle tissue as the heart, so as not to tire out - attached to a [bottle dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_dynamo). You would achieve much the same effect.

Now, the fuel for these reactors is food itself. This solves a big problem, since you can reuse the body's natural feeding and exhaust lines. Also no need to get dangrous chemicals such as petrol, nor radioactive stuff into someone. Keep it safe!

And remember, humans can spend a **lot** of energy in a day. Check out [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)#106_to_1011_J) from wikipedia. A regular caloric intake for an adult is as much energy as what would be released by detonating two kilograms of TNT, or more than two kWh. That is enough to power a lot of equipment. If a cyborg just eats like Michael Phelps and has robotic arms, they would be able to throw punches with the stopping power of grenade blasts.

Comment: Soory, but this is not the solution. OP wants high power. (he is considering fusion...) This would only convert a small part of the cyborgy natural 'biochemical metabolic power' into electricity. No new energy source in the system.

Comment: @b.Lorenz what I am proposing here would allow a cyborg to throw punches with the force of grenade blasts. 2 kcal of food per day don't seem much to most people because just 2 is a very small number, but that is over eight million joules. If the cyborg just eats more than a human would (which can be done, since OP is willing to accept "edited" human biology), they could have the energy output of a small flamethrower just for implants.

Comment: But how will these cyborgs defeat the enemy with their Bluetooth MP3 breasts? https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: The OP asked for a biological solution via genetic manipulation.  Is your answer officially "you can't do that, so try the following..."?

Comment: @JBH indeed. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @Demigan - more like this: youtu.be/aTe0MjAZvMU

Answer (score 1):

So normal everyday humans use bioreactors called mitochondria to generate energy. They literally burn fuel, reacting fats and sugars with oxygen and use the heat generated to convert adenosine diphosphate (ADP) to adenosine triphosphate ([ATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate)). The energy from burning food is stored in the transition from ADP to ATP. ATP goes where it's needed and the energy is released by converting back to ADP. I recall from biology that ADP is like a spring or grip crusher, and the addition of an additional phosphate group twists the molecule into a high energy configuration - like compressing a spring and locking it. Pop the lock and let it decompress to release the energy. I'm thinking that that's more analogy than how it physically works, however, one of the answers on [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-function-of-ATP) did mention that the ATPase moves like a water wheel when the extra phosphate group is added or removed.

So how to mess with this? Go from chemical mitochondria to nuclear powered ones and just flood the body with ADP/ATP to handle the increased energy production and use. You'd never get tired - like a hyperactive kid in the throes of an intense sugar rush, but you might start running into issues of over heating or parts of the body wearing out due to overuse since they aren't used to having and endless supply of energy. So if you start making additional mods to handle those issues, might as well take it one step further and replace the ADP/ATP with a different molecule that can store much more energy. This will help with moving more energy more quickly for, say, explosive movements.

Comment: ADP to ATP and back is a chemical energy, while heat might be released upon use and some heat energy might be captured upon binding, just using any heatsource for regenerating ATP isnt going to work. Otherwise, why would the human body have developed one of the best systems to lose heat to the environment during hard work?

Comment: Yes. enzymes are used to convert energy stored in chemical bonds into movement. Of course there's a waste heat issue that has to be dealt with - no system is 100% efficient. So any heat source (the definition of heat being transfer of kinetic energy on a molecular scale) can be used to charge ADP to ATP if the appropriate enzymes are used - tailor made enzymes would just have to be part of messing with the body's energy cycle.

Comment: Maybe this will explain better: using a heatsource for the creation of ATP is like having a tree grow faster by binding the heat from a fire into the wood. Its not something the tree is capable of. Heat is a byproduct of the release of phosphate from ATP, but heat is not (actively) used to bind phosphate into an ADP to form ATP.

Comment: I think we agree and are talking past each other. If the tree is set on fire it has no way to use the heat (well that and the fire is pretty indiscriminate when it comes to the fuel being used). If the tree has plenty of burnable fuel in a form that it's mitochondria can use (sugar) and the they are reacting that fuel in the specific and appropriate way along with ATPase, then the tree will grow faster. I think we are arguing of the use of the word "heat." I'm just looking at energy release from reacting 02 with sugar. Some is waste and some is captured in the addition of a phosphate group.

Comment: so you are arguing for an increase of the energy to create ATP and used "heat". I understand now. But I'm not sure how you want to speed up thr ATP generation. The most lucrative method is using oxygen, the faster method is using anaerobic and continuously cycling the lactate to the Liver and back to the muscles. From the answers in my superhuman questions I would guess that one of the best ways to improve current chemical energy production is by placing clumps of livercells near muscles to speed up processing, and faster O2/CO2 transport.

Comment: @Demigan So the idea here is to bypass the O2/CO2 issue altogether by using a higher energy (nuclear) reaction. That'll cause all sorts of other issues, but hey, one thing at a time. We're trying to co-opt existing energy transfer mechanisms to capture energy released from - let's go with aneutronic fusion, instead of the energy from an oxidation reaction, as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a lot of energy is not an issue, you don't even need to modify anything. You just need to eat a lot of simple carbs. You can extract a lot of energy in a fast and efficient way from simple carbohydrates.
What modification you DO need is to prevent insulin resistance (diabetes).